# Clear previous screen to show next screen pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to develop GUI for a who wants to be a millionaire game using pygame. If the user is presented with the welcome screen and clicks new game, it should clear the welcome screen and bring up the main game screen.

I tried using os.system('xxx.py') but it doesnt stay on, it just flashes and goes off. 
Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

You probably shouldn't be trying to launch a new instance of your game. You should create a reset method which can be called to restart everything. It would clear all variables, set the game state back to the start, etc.